# UIControl blocking all my views on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uicontrol

I got a iPad-designed app using a `SplitViewController` showing two views, one with a contacts list and another with details of this contact. The `SplitView` works well on iPad but has some problems on iPhones.

There is a UIControl that take all the size of the Master View, that check if there is any `.touchDown interaction` by the user and some methods called to enable or disable this `UIControl` depending if we are on editing contact mode or not allowing user to interact with the screen or not :

```
private var disableInteractionClosure: (()->())?
    private lazy var interactionOverlay: UIControl = {
        let c = UIControl()
        c.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
        c.addTarget(self, action: "interactionOverlayAction", forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
        return c
    }()

    func disableInteractionWhileEditingWithClosure(callback: ()->()) {
        if disableInteractionClosure == nil {
            disableInteractionClosure = callback
            /* display control overlay */
            interactionOverlay.frame = navigationController!.view.bounds
            navigationController!.view.addSubview(interactionOverlay)
        }
    }

    func interactionOverlayAction() {
        disableInteractionClosure!()
    }

    func enableInteraction() {
        disableInteractionClosure = nil
        interactionOverlay.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

Basically the `UIControl` **is used to block user from switching between contact while user is editing another contact/ creating a new one by blocking interaction with the contact list** and if changes have been made on the editing/creating view it fires a method that shows a pop up saying "modifications have been made do you want to continue without saving ? cancel or continue " :

```
func cancel() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        let closure: ()->() = {
            self.layoutView.willResign()
            self.delegate?.tabDetailsControllerDidCancel(self)
        }

            if layoutView.hasChanges() {
                MKAlertViewController().instantaneousAlert(title: "Modification apportées", message: "Êtes-vous sur de vouloir continuer sans sauvegarder les modifications ?", confirmButtonTitle: "Oui", cancelButtonTitle: "Annuler", confirmed: { () -> Void in
                    closure()
                    }, canceled: { () -> Void in

                })
            } else {
                closure()
            }

    }
```

It works fine on iPad because the `UIControl` is only above the Master View and is enabled when in editing mode on the Detail View ([iPad 3D Debugging view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8eqQ.png)), so the pop up shows only when manually cancelling the editing/creating or when trying to change contact while editing/creating, but as the `splitView` don't work the same on iPads and iPhones and it appears that on iPhone the Master View is placed above the Detail View,  the `UIControl` is also above ([iPhone 3D Debugging view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfIxK.png)), and it causes to block interactions on all the screen and wherever I click the cancel pop-up is shown.

Can you guys explain me a way to enable/show this UIControl only when the MasterView is showing and not everywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `viewWillDisappear` on the detail view :

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if self.isMovingFromParentViewController() || self.isBeingDismissed() {
            if editingMode {
                shared.contactsListController.disableInteractionWhileEditingWithClosure({ (_) in
                    self.tabDetailsController.cancel()
                })
                shared.contactsListController.disableToolbar()
            } else {
                shared.contactsListController.enableInteraction()
                shared.contactsListController.enableToolbar()
            }
            self.navigationController?.toolbar.alpha = 1
        }
    }
```

and modifying the `disableInteractionWhileEditingWithClosure` method on the master view:

```
func disableInteractionWhileEditingWithClosure(callback: ()->()) {
        if disableInteractionClosure == nil {
            disableInteractionClosure = callback
            /* display control overlay */
            interactionOverlay.frame = navigationController!.view.bounds

            view.addSubview(interactionOverlay) // this line
        }
    }
```

and it works ! :)